# Setting a nested array field from a non nested field mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested

I want to set a field that was originally top level to each  item on an array,

for example i have

```
{
 myField = "Hello",
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1}, {nmbr:2}]
}
```

now I want:

```
{
 myField = "Hello",
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1, myField: "Hello"}, {nmbr:2, myField :"Hello"}]
}
```

using:

```
db.collection.update( {"myObjects": {$exists: true}}, { $set: { "myObjects.$[].myField": "$myField" } }, { multi: true })
```

has this result

```
{
 myField = "Hello",
 myObjects = [ {nmbr: 1, myField:"$myField"}, {nmbr:2, myField:"$myField"}]
}
```

which is not what I expected, any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `Aggregation` framework, like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      "myObjects.myField": "$myField"
    }
  }
],
{
  "multi": true
})
```

Here is the working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/u3RaeMPCrAy

Comment: adding an $out at this aggregation made the job thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that you wanted to update the documents. You can also use Aggregation framework in "update" query, as a second parameter. I updated my answer.